# I cannot access my in app purchase all I get is :

Tags: in-app-purchase

I'm trying to learn in app purchase I have upload an app which is  a test app, rejected the binary so it has the status rejected by developer.

I created an in app purchase product, but I have this warning at the top :

Your first In-App Purchase(s) must be submitted with a new app version. Select them from the In-App Purchases section of the Version Details page and then click Ready to Upload Binary.

and the status of my in app purchase is always :

ready to subnmit.

I tried to re submit my test app, so that status was back to waiting for review, then went too my in app purchase it still had the same line above at the top and still the status of ready to submit.

I then re rejected my my main binary but the status of my in app purchase is still the same.

I dont understand how I can go from there.

Tks for all the help !

Serge

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I didn't read the instruction properly, but going back to my general app , in the view details a new section appeared where I could link my in app purchases to the app, I missed it somehow.

might help somebody else that missed it too !